# Detect PDF pages with markup?

Tags: python, pdf

Let's say I have a PDF file with a few strikethroughs and comments.

I am searching for any tool that can tell me what are the number of pages that has markup ( comments and so on ) or if there is a python library I can use to do this ?

Comment: **can I even do this in python**. Last time I checked, python was capable of opening a file, that is all you need to be able to do this. Perhaps you mean are there any libraries that can do that.

Comment: Yes, I mean libraries. I don't have time to spend looking into the PDF format.